# How to close GNOME Terminal search window shortcut key?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to open the Search window.
Now whenever I am done searching I would like to close this window.
I'd expect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to do this, however nothing happens when doing pressing that keyboard combo. I looked at the shortcuts preferences, but I do not see a close option there, other than closing a tab (which does work).

I can't imagine there really is no shortcut for closing a search window. Does anyone know about it?

System info:
Ubuntu 17.10
GNOME Shell 3.26.2
GNOME Terminal 3.24.2

[image: screenshot of search window]

Comment: Upstream bugreport: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=771165.

Answer (score 4):

and if the <kbd>Esc</kbd> won't work for you, you can always use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: Both don't work on my system. Probably due to the bug egmont reported.

Answer (score 2):

Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> worked just fine for me. It works for closing most modal windows.